# intellij Gradle Sync Error : "Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'."

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.REALEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:')
}
```

and this is the Sync ErrorMessage

> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.7.REALEASE.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.1.7.REALEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.1.7.REALEASE.pom
> > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.1.7.REALEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.1.7.REALEASE.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

There are clearly declared repositories like mavenCentral() and jcnenter(), but can't build it.

Comment: Is it possible to build for command line outside IDE?

Comment: I tried in cmd (using command "gradle build"), but still gave me an error message "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."

Comment: Do you face the same issue with one Gradle project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told jcenter no longer be serviced, so I changed dependencies and deleted jcenter().

This build is successfully worked.

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```